# Algolia geo search is not returning results

Tags: flutter, algolia

Geo search not returning results. If I do not use geo search, it works fine.

I am using algolia 0.1.3+2 dart client for Flutter
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/algolia#-readme-tab-

Query in Flutter

```
StreamBuilder(
stream: algolia.instance.index('Geo').setAroundLatLng('latitude,longitude')
.getObjects().asStream(),

builder: (context, liveInvitesSnap){ ...
```

Algolia data structure

https://i.ibb.co/3cv7J4X/Screen-Shot-2019-02-04-at-3-58-16-pm.png